# How to make printed pdf files authentic to prevent forging or cloning using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

please i have a web application developed using asp.net which generates certificates (pdf files) using data in xml files. What can i include (e.g like using a barcode or something) to make the certificates authentic to make it impossible to forge or clone. I have been on this for like a week now. Google hasn't been helpful either. Please assist.
thanks

Comment: To prevent forgery digitally sign the PDF. If you are trying to make something that someone can print out but can't be forged this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain how to achieve this, but as is customary on SO, you'll have to write the code yourself.

You are creating a PDF file based on XML data. When the document is printed, you can't use a digital signature as digital signatures check the validity of the document at the byte level: a hash is created of the document, this hash is signed with a private key (some extra stuff is added) and that signed hash is integrated into the file.

Now when somebody wants to check the integrity of the file, a new hash of the bytes in the file is created (hash #1) and the encrypted hash is decrypted (hash #2) using the public key that corresponds with the private key that was used to encrypt the hash. If hash #1 differs from hash #2, the document was forged.

When you print a document, there are no bytes to check. As Chris Haas points out, you can't protect the document. However: you can protect the data. For instance, you could add the original XML to the document in the form of a 2D barcode (you can choose which type of barcode). This way, people can scan the original data. You can then add a second barcode. For instance: you make a hash of the original XML and you encrypt it with a private key. You add this encrypted hash as a barcode (you may have to use Base64 encoding).

Now when somebody has scanned the first barcode for the data, he can scan the second barcode for the "signature". He needs to decrypt the scanned signature using the public key and compare the resulting hash with a hash of the scanned data. If both hashes are identical, the scanned data equals the original data.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno. Are my going to hash the contents of the first barcode? please provide an example if possible.

Comment: *"Are my going to hash the contents"* isn't a real question; please rephrase. As for an example: please follow the rules on StackOverflow and show us what you've tried.